# Aura component not getting recordId in one.app page

Tags: aura

The view page for a particular SObject is overwritten by a Visualpage page that is inside a managed package. When you click the edit button (not inline editing which works fine) and save, the URL switches from 'lightning/r/object__c/a8txxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view' to 'one/one.app#[long hash]'.

There is a Utility Item we wrote using an Aura component. The Aura component uses the standard

```
var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
```

to get the Id of the record we are viewing. This works fine with the first URL (lightning/r), but does not work with the second URL (one.app). In the latter case, `v.recordId` returns nothing.

I have tried to use the javascript `atob` method to decode the hash (retrieved by using `window.location.hash` from the one.app URL), but I get this error: "The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded".

```
const hashValue = window.location.hash;
    
if (hashValue) {
    var encodedString = hashValue.substring(1);
    const decodedData = atob(encodedString);
}
```

I have also tried to use `lightning/pageReferenceUtils` and the `decodeDefaultFieldValues` method, but that just returns an empty object.

```
const hashValue = window.location.hash;
var encodedString = hashValue.substring(1);
const dfvObject = component.find("pageRefUtil").decodeDefaultFieldValues(encodedString);
```

Is there another way to get the recordId from one.app or am I just chasing rainbows?